# AndroidViewClient tap specific X,Y coordinate

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

What is the correct way to touch a specific X,Y coordinate on screen using AndroidViewClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of discovering and learning **AndroidViewClient** is by using `culebra` as a script generator.

Start [culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) as

```
culebra -uG --scale=0.5
```

click with the alternate button to open the context menu and select **Touch using DIP** or **Touch using PX** and the autogenerated script will contains something like

```
device.touchDip(139.33, 426.0, 0)
```

or

```
device.touch(250.0, 1242.0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks dtmilano, I was hoping you'd be the one to notice this question; I've been making a lot of use of Culebra since you introduced it in a previous question on SO. Would you have any insight here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102723/androidviewclient-restarts-device-with-every-command

Comment: if I actually just run this verbatim as Culebra generates it, it will just restart my virtual device and then all further Culebra-generated scripts will do the same thing (just restart the device). That's related to the link in the above comment - have you ever encountered this? Right now I'm using a Google Galaxy Nexus 4.3 API 18 virtual device

Comment: Try same scripts on emulator and you may be able to isolate the problem if it's strictly related to your device.