# AndroidViewClient restarts device with every command after using "touch(x,y)" command once

Tags: android, androidviewclient

Using AndroidViewClient, just recently every action I try to make using Culebra or any of the associated scripts just restarts the virtual device.  Has anyone ever run into this before?

**edit 1: ** More specifically, I get into this endless restart loop only *after* trying a command where I touch the device in a specific area.

i.e. If I place the following into my script, it will just restart the device and then all further Culebra generated commands will just cause the device to restart

`self.vc.device.touchDip(173, 1111)`

**edit 2: Added more information**
I've replicated this behavior on a few different models, but I'm primarily working with the following:

Device: Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280

```
$ culebra -v
culebra 10.7.2

$ dump -v
dump 10.7.2

dump
android.widget.FrameLayout  
 android.view.View com.android.launcher:id/workspace 
  android.view.View com.android.launcher:id/cell3 
     android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView  
        android.view.View com.android.deskclock:id/analog_appwidget 
     android.widget.TextView  Camera
....

$ adb shell date
Thu Aug 20 12:44:08 EDT 2015
```

Different x,y coordinates restart the device as well:

```
adb shell input tap 200 900 <--- restarts the phone as well
```

**Edit 3: Screenshot after logged into adb shell**
The phone restarts again after the second command here
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never heard of such thing, then I guess is something related to your particular environment, device or version (details missing from your question).

Anyway, instead of a solution, which I don't have as I don't know the problem I will give you some tips to find the cause.

First of all, check that `adb` is working and you can connect to the device:

adb shell

**AndroidViewClient/culebra** uses `input tap` command to send touch events, then send something like

```
adb shell input tap 173 1111
```

ignore the DIP for the moment, just send the coordinates in PX.

Additionally, test `dump` to verify that the content of the screen can be obtained

```
dump -a
```

I hope this helps you detect the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I confirmed that just that command there does in fact restart the phone - "adb shell input tap 369 1113" should correspond to tapping the home button on a Google Galaxy Nexus 4.3 (720x1280), but instead that command itself just restarts the phone

Comment: what about different x,y? reboots too?

Comment: what about `adb shell date`, reboots too?

Comment: I've just added more info to the original post.  `adb shell input tap 200 900` restarted the device as well

Comment: Try `adb shell` first, and when you are at the shell prompt issue the `input` commands. In case they print some errors you'll be able to see it.

Comment: Same thing - I posted a screenshot in my original question... hmm would it be related to not running from my machine this as root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87512/discussion-between-tim5046-and-dtmilano).

Comment: Accepting this as the right answer, since the issue seems to lie with the Genymotion emulator rather than AndroidViewClient