# adb touch with Genymotion restarts the device every time

Tags: android, genymotion, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

Using Genymotion as the virtual device, any time I run even a very simple adb touch (x,y) command to touch the device at any (x,y) coordinate, the virtual phone just restarts.

Is there some sort of setting that you need to configure with Genymotion to allow automated touches?  I've never seen this behavior before with monkeyrunner

Here's the simple script:

```
$monkeyrunner touchtest.py
```

**touchtest.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)
device.touch(426, 1140, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

When running this, the phone just restarts instead of registering any touch command

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `monkeyrunner` or `AndroidViewClient/culebra` have nothing to do with this Genymotion problem as it happens from command line too (`adb input tap x y`) as was determined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102723/androidviewclient-restarts-device-with-every-command-after-using-touchx-y-co/32109778?noredirect=1#comment52141451_32109778 . So to help locate the problem I would remove `monkeyrunner` references from the question.

Comment: Ah correct, updated. Thanks!